# Is there a way to unaccept WhatsApp's new terms and privacy policy?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, privacy

As you may know, WhatsApp's new terms and privacy policy are currently **optional**, as ["we currently have no plans for these reminders to become persistent and to limit the functionality of the app"](https://faq.whatsapp.com/general/security-and-privacy/what-happens-when-our-terms-and-privacy-policy-updates-take-effect/).

But those reminders are easily clickable. So if someone that I know accidentally clicked them, is there any way to "undo" it and return to "reminder mode"?

[image: WhatsApp policy reminder]

Comment: Go to settings and force - stop the app

Comment: @beeshyams umm, did you mean "clear data"?

Comment: That said, I don't remember if this privacy policy is per account, per device, or per installation. If it's per account, then I doubt there's any way to reset since it's stored on the WhatsApp server. If it's per device/installation, then clearing data may reset the value (**warning: untested, may also remove all chats**).

Comment: It's a good question, but not worth testing due to this risk. I wish someone maybe like a newspaper/blogger were to test it by buying a new number to avoid the risk of losing anything.